# Как получить json из post-запроса

Tags: php

Есть 2 файла. Первый обращается ко второму методом post и передает json

```php
$url = '/test.php';


$json = json_encode(['name' => 'Имя', 'phone' => '88000000000']);

$options = ['http' => [
    'method' => 'POST',
    'header' => 'Content-type:application/json',
    'content' => http_build_query($json)
]];
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

А второй должен его принимать и записывать в файл. Но я не понимаю как во втором файле получить и обработать этот json? Пробую вот так, не получается:

```php
$fd = fopen("result.txt", 'a') or die("не удалось создать файл");
$str = $_POST.PHP_EOL;
fwrite($fd, $str);
fclose($fd);
```

Массив $_POST пустой, а где тогда json?

Comment: `file_get_contents("php://input")`

Comment: А в $str данные есть?

Comment: @43oi5uo34iu5 нотис там есть про конкатенацию массива и EOL

Comment: @43oi5uo34iu5 Строка содержит "Array". Ну я не очень удачный пример написал, Array этот пустой короче

Comment: @teran `$str = file_get_contents("php://input").PHP_EOL; ` - типа вот так? Что-то в файл ничего не записывается при этом.

Comment: у вас вообще это скрипты на разных сайтах? или почему такое взаимодействие выбрано?

Comment: "Строка содержит "Array"" потому что вы не понимаете что происходит при конкатенации массива и строки.

Comment: А сделать сначала надо `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: @teran Скрипты на одном сайте пока, но в перспективе первый скрипт должен отдавать этот json на внешний сайт, где у меня не будет возможности его проверить. Поэтому я хочу пока проверить что с ним все нормально так.

Comment: @u_mulder дя, я это уже понял, но `$str = file_get_contents('php://input').PHP_EOL;` тоже не дает результата

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в вызывающем файле во-первых укажите полный url с протоколом и хостом. Во-вторых,  не надо использовать `http_build_query`, у вас же нет ассоциативного массива ключ-значение, который вы отправляете, а просто данные.

пример вызывающего

```
$url = 'http://test/test2.php';
$json = json_encode(['name' => 'Имя', 'phone' => '88000000000']);

$options = ['http' => [
    'method' => 'POST',
    'header' => 'Content-type:application/json',
    'content' => $json
]];

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);


echo $response;
```

в вызываемом используйте поток `php://input` для получения данных запроса. `$_POST` у вас пуст, поскольку опять таки у вас не было массива ключ-значение

```
$raw = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($raw, true);
echo $data['name'];
```

при такой паре файлов в результате работы будет выведена строка `Имя`

Comment: Убрать `http_build_query` действительно помогло, спасибо. А адрес и так с протоколом был, просто здесь я написал иначе.